# Find all primes from 1 million random integers in less than 6 seconds

Tags: c

I'm supposed to improve this code using multithreading to sum and count all prime numbers of one million randomly generated integers in less than 6 seconds. My professor did it in less than a second how do I do so I'm stuck.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <math.h>

int isPrime(int num) {
    int i;
    for (i = 2; i < num; i++) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Too few arguments ");
        printf("USAGE: ./primeCalc <prime pivot> <num of random numbers>");
        exit(0);
    }

    int randomPivot = atoi(argv[1]);
    int numOfRandomNumbers = atoi(argv[2]);
    long sum = 0;
    long primeCounter = 0;
    
    //init rundom generator
    int random = rand();
    srand(randomPivot);

    //generate random numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfRandomNumbers; i++) {
        random = rand();
        //check if the number is prime
        if (isPrime(random)) {
            //if do, add up it's sum, and increment counter
            sum = sum + random;
            primeCounter++;
        }   
    }
    //keep the out format as this!!
    printf("%ld,%ld\n", sum, primeCounter);
    exit(0);
}
```

I tried using this code but, for some reason, the output was wrong and it only used 1 core even though I used 3 threads.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <math.h>

pthread_mutex_t lock;

long count1 = 0, count2 = 0, count3 = 0;
long sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0, sum3 = 0;

void *isPrime1(void *x) {
    int i; int num = *(int*)x;
    if (num < 2)
        return NULL;
    if (num == 2)
        return NULL;
    {
        sum1 += num;
        count1 += 1; 
    }
    if (num % 2 == 0)
        return NULL;

    for (i = 3; i * i < num; i = i + 2) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    sum1 += num;
    count1 += 1;

    return NULL;
}

void *isPrime2(void *x) {
    int i;
    int num = *(int*)x;
    if (num < 2)
        return NULL;
    if (num == 2)
        return NULL;
    {
        sum2 += num;
        count2 += 1;
    }
    if (num % 2 == 0)
        return NULL;

    for (i = 3; i * i < num; i = i + 2) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    sum2 += num;
    count2 += 1;

    return NULL;
}

void *isPrime3(void *x) {
    int i;
    int num = *(int*)x;
    if (num < 2)
        return NULL;
    if (num == 2)
        return NULL;
    {
        sum3 += num;
        count3 += 1;
    }
    if (num % 2 == 0)
        return NULL;

    for (i = 3; i * i < num; i = i + 2) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    sum3 += num;
    count3 += 1;

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL) != 0) {
        printf("mutix init failed\n");
        return 0;
    }

    pthread_t tids[3];

    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Too few arguments ");
        printf("USAGE: ./primeCalc <prime pivot> <num of random numbers>");
        exit(0);
    }

    int randomPivot = atoi(argv[1]);
    int numOfRandomNumbers = atoi(argv[2]);

    //init rundom generator

    int random = rand();

    srand(randomPivot);

    //generate random numbers

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfRandomNumbers; i += 3) {
        random = rand();

        pthread_create((&tids[0]), NULL, isPrime1, &random);
        random = rand();

        pthread_create((&tids[1]), NULL, isPrime2, &random);
        random = rand();
        pthread_create((&tids[2]), NULL, isPrime3, &random);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        pthread_join(tids[j], NULL);
    long sum = sum1 + sum2 + sum3;
    long count = count1 + count2 + count3;

    //keep the out format as this!!
    printf("%ld,%ld\n", sum, count);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Second thing to try: check for odd/even once... then check only odd numbers: `for (i = 3; i < num; i += 2) { ... }`. For first thing see @qrdl's comment :-)

Comment: What have you done to try and get un-"stuck"?

Comment: `for (i = 2;i<num;i++)` - do you need to iterate up to `num`?

Comment: Your code doesn't use any threads right now. It should.

Comment: Supposing all the input values fit in `int`, first find all prime numbers up to the square root of `INT_MAX` and store them in a table (array). Then, for each candidate number, test whether it is divisible by each stored prime number (but is not equal to that stored number). If it is, it is not prime. Otherwise, it is prime. (Exception: if the candidate is less than 2, it is neither prime nor composite.)

Comment: the way to find all primes is to use a sieve. Your method is only for checking individual numbers and it's far from efficient even for that purpose

Comment: @phuclv: The task is not to find all primes.

Comment: In the new code, each thread created tests just one number. That is absurd. To test n numbers with t threads, make each thread test about n/t numbers. Design the thread routine to accept a number of numbers to test. And write one routine that can do the job; do not use a unique routine for each thread. They should report their results through a pointer to data they are passed, and the main thread should combine those results. Do not use external variables for that.

Comment: @EricPostpischil but each thread test a different number cause i used random=rand() before each thread so the number changes

Comment: @HosamHegleh: That each thread tests a different number is irrelevant. The point is each thread tests only **one** number. That means your program creates a thread, the thread tests one number, the thread ends, and the main thread joins it. That is hugely wasteful. To test n numbers, you create n threads. The time to create and join a thread is large compare to the time to test one number. You should create **only** some small number t of threads, and each thread should test about n/t numbers.

Comment: @EricPostpischil ah i get it thanks

Comment: There is also a race condition between the three threads in each set, because they all use a pointer to the same variable.

Comment: Try with sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for threads to achieve your goal, all you need are small improvements to the `isPrime()` function:

- test even numbers explicitly
- only test odd numbers in the loop
- stop the loop when `i > num / i`.
- return `0` for `0` and `1`

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int isPrime(int num) {
    int i;
    if ((num & 1) == 0)
        return num == 2;
    for (i = 3; i <= num / i; i += 2) {
        if (num % i == 0)
            return 0;
    }
    return num != 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Too few arguments\n");
        printf("USAGE: ./primeCalc <prime pivot> <num of random numbers>\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    int randomPivot = atoi(argv[1]);
    int numOfRandomNumbers = atoi(argv[2]);
    long sum = 0;
    long primeCounter = 0;

    srand(randomPivot);  //init rundom generator

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfRandomNumbers; i++) {
        int random = rand();
        if (isPrime(random)) {
            sum = sum + random;
            primeCounter++;
        }
    }
    printf("%ld,%ld\n", sum, primeCounter);
    return 0;
}
```

Output on my 2015 slow laptop:

```
~/dev/stackoverflow > time ./primeCalc 0 1000000
50915866465059,48687

real    0m4.151s
user    0m4.119s
sys     0m0.011s
```

To further improve the performance, we can precompute the prime numbers less or equal to the square root of `RAND_MAX`, reducing the number of divisions for large prime numbers. Furthermore, the loop test can use a mutiplication as the prime factor candidates are all below square root of `INT_MAX`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int primes[4793]; /* There are 4792 primes <= sqrt(0x7fffffff) */

int isPrime(int num) {
    if ((num & 1) == 0)
        return num == 2;
    for (int *p = primes + 1; *p && (*p) * (*p) <= num; p++) {
        if (num % *p == 0)
            return 0;
    }
    return num != 1;
}

void initPrimes(int max) {
    int i = 0, p;
    primes[i++] = 2;
    for (p = 3; p <= max / p; p += 2) {
        if (isPrime(p))
            primes[i++] = p;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Too few arguments\n");
        printf("USAGE: ./primeCalc <prime pivot> <num of random numbers>\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    int randomPivot = atoi(argv[1]);
    int numOfRandomNumbers = atoi(argv[2]);
    long sum = 0;
    long primeCounter = 0;

    initPrimes(RAND_MAX);

    srand(randomPivot);  //init rundom generator

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfRandomNumbers; i++) {
        int random = rand();
        if (isPrime(random)) {
            sum = sum + random;
            primeCounter++;
        }
    }
    printf("%ld,%ld\n", sum, primeCounter);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
~/dev/stackoverflow > ./primeCalc1 0 1000000
50915866465059,48687

real    0m0.580s
user    0m0.566s
sys     0m0.004s
```

This result is consistent with your teacher's result, yet without threads.

You can further improve the timings using threads but there is a catch: for your test, you want to compute the same random numbers, which is not guaranteed if `rand()` is called from different threads. You thus need to compute the random numbers in the main thread and store them in an array, then use separate threads separate parts of the array and combine the results. I suggest you store the arguments and results in a separate structure for each thread and pass a pointer to it as the opaque argument.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

static int primes[4793];  /* There are 4792 primes <= sqrt(0x7fffffff) */

int isPrime(int num) {
    if ((num & 1) == 0)
        return num == 2;
    for (int *p = primes + 1; *p && (*p) * (*p) <= num; p++) {
        if (num % *p == 0)
            return 0;
    }
    return num != 1;
}

void initPrimes(int max) {
    int i = 0, p;
    primes[i++] = 2;
    for (p = 3; p <= max / p; p += 2) {
        if (isPrime(p))
            primes[i++] = p;
    }
}

struct primeCalcArgs {
    pthread_t tid;
    int *array;
    int start, end;
    long sum, count;
};

void *primeCalcTask(void *opaque) {
    struct primeCalcArgs *p = opaque;
    int *array = p->array;
    p->sum = 0;
    p->count = 0;
    for (int i = p->start; i < p->end; i++) {
        if (isPrime(array[i])) {
            p->sum += array[i];
            p->count++;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "primeCalc: Too few arguments\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: ./primeCalc <prime pivot> <num of random numbers> [<nb of threads>]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int randomPivot = atoi(argv[1]);
    int numOfRandomNumbers = atoi(argv[2]);
    int numOfThreads = argc > 3 ? atoi(argv[3]) : 1;
    long sum = 0;
    long count = 0;

    if (numOfThreads < 1)
        numOfThreads = 1;

    if (numOfRandomNumbers > 0) {
        int i, n;

        initPrimes(RAND_MAX);

        int *array = malloc(sizeof(*array) * numOfRandomNumbers);
        if (!array) {
            fprintf(stderr, "primeCalc: cannot allocate random number array\n");
            return 1;
        }
        srand(randomPivot);  //init rundom generator
        for (i = 0; i < numOfRandomNumbers; i++) {
            array[i] = rand();
        }
        struct primeCalcArgs args[numOfThreads];
        for (n = 0; n < numOfThreads; n++) {
            args[n].array = array;
            args[n].start = (long long)numOfRandomNumbers * n / numOfThreads;
            args[n].end = (long long)numOfRandomNumbers * (n + 1) / numOfThreads;
            args[n].sum = 0;
            args[n].count = 0;
            if (pthread_create(&args[n].tid, NULL, primeCalcTask, &args[n])) {
                fprintf(stderr, "primeCalc: cannot create thread %d\n", n + 1);
                break;
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            pthread_join(args[i].tid, NULL);
            sum += args[i].sum;
            count += args[i].count;
        }
        free(array);
    }
    printf("%ld,%ld\n", sum, count);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
~/dev/stackoverflow > time ./primeCalc 0 1000000
50915866465059,48687

real    0m0.581s
user    0m0.565s
sys     0m0.007s

~/dev/stackoverflow > time ./primeCalc 0 1000000 2
50915866465059,48687

real    0m0.293s
user    0m0.552s
sys     0m0.006s

~/dev/stackoverflow > time ./primeCalc 0 1000000 3
50915866465059,48687

real    0m0.286s
user    0m0.739s
sys     0m0.007s

~/dev/stackoverflow > time ./primeCalc 0 1000000 4
50915866465059,48687

real    0m0.242s
user    0m0.846s
sys     0m0.006s

~/dev/stackoverflow > time ./primeCalc 0 1000000 5
50915866465059,48687

real    0m0.245s
user    0m0.845s
sys     0m0.008s

~/dev/stackoverflow > time ./primeCalc 0 1000000 10
50915866465059,48687

real    0m0.281s
user    0m0.858s
sys     0m0.008s

~/dev/stackoverflow > time ./primeCalc 0 1000000 100
50915866465059,48687

real    0m0.279s
user    0m0.846s
sys     0m0.012s

~/dev/stackoverflow > time ./primeCalc 0 1000000 10000
50915866465059,48687

real    0m1.274s
user    0m0.752s
sys     0m1.663s
```

As you can see, my laptop has full 2 cores: the real time is exactly half for 2 threads. It gets marginal improvements from its hyper-threading capability for 3 and 4 threads but no improvement for more than 4 threads. Performance actually degrades for extra threads and I am even surprised that requesting 10000 threads succeeds and still performs reasonably well.

For larger counts of random numbers, I would suggest using a sieve to compute a bitmap of all primes up to `RAND_MAX`, adding a fixed overhead to the whole process. On my laptop, this sieve takes one or two seconds and makes the prime test immediate, leaving just the overhead of the random number generator.

Comment: You can change `i <= num / i` to the equivalent `i*i <= num` to get rid of a division.

Comment: @dbush: true but the multiplication might overflow for `num` close to `INT_MAX`, which can happen for random numbers.  Furthermore the division is combined with the modulo operation by efficient compilers.

Comment: @dbush: So much for *efficient compilers*... I double checked this bold claim and to my dismay **clang** does not combine division and modulo operations, even in simple code, whereas **gcc** does for the posted code. Using `(unsigned)i * i <= (unsigned)num` reduces the run time by 40% on my Macbook. The code generation can be seen here: https://godbolt.org/z/P3K8orPnh