# how to reduce a processing time of a simple program for calculating prime numbers?

Tags: c

I got a C code, The usage is like this: `./primeSolution 6 100`, where 6 is the seed for the random number generator,
and 100 is the amount of numbers it needs to check prime numbers. The output is the sum of the primes were found, and the amount of them. I need to develop solution to find a way to check a number for being a prime or not, as fast as I can, I should use a multithreads and also mutex to solve this, my code is attached here in this code I just defined the threads and mutex but not used, I am asking how to use it to get better processing time.

Output and processing time I get now for `time ./c 6 1000` is:

```
55560315251,55
real    0m0.065s
user    0m0.052s
sys     0m0.000s
```

---

output and processing time I should get maximum for `time ./c 6 1000`:

```
55560315251,55

real    0m0.010s
user    0m0.009s
sys     0m0.001s
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <math.h>

pthread_mutex_t lock;
//long sum = 0;
//long primeCounter = 0;

int isPrime(int n) {
    int i, flag;
    // Iterate from 2 to sqrt(n)
    for (i = 2; i <= sqrt(n); i++) {
        // If n is divisible by any number between
        // 2 and n/2, it is not prime
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pthread_t thread_1;
    pthread_t thread_2;

    pthread_create(&thread_1, NULL, isPrime, NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread_2, NULL, isPrime, NULL);

    if (pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL) != 0) {
        printf("fail init mutex!");
    }

    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Too few arguments ");
        printf("USAGE: ./primeCalc <prime pivot> <num of random numbers>");
        exit(0);
    }

    int randomPivot = atoi(argv[1]);
    int numOfRandomNumbers = atoi(argv[2]);
    long sum = 0;
    long primeCounter = 0;
    
    //init rundom generator
    int random = rand();
    srand(randomPivot);

    //generate random numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfRandomNumbers; i++) {
        random = rand();
        //check if the number is prime
        if (isPrime(random)) {
            //if do, add up it's sum, and increment counter
            sum = sum + random;
            primeCounter++;
        }   
    }
    //keep the out format as this!!
    printf("%ld,%ld\n", sum, primeCounter);
    
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);

    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not really using threads for any purpose whatsoever... but the goal is definitely achievable without them. Here is a faster version of `isPrime`:

```
int isPrime(int n) {
    // special test for even numbers (50% of random numbers)
    if ((n & 1) == 0) {
        return n == 2;
    } else {
        int i, max = sqrt(n);
        // Iterate from 3 to sqrt(n)
        for (i = 3; i <= max; i += 2) {
            // If n is divisible by any number between
            // 3 and sqrt(n), it is not prime
            if (n % i == 0) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        // special test for 1 (often forgotten)
        return n != 1;
    }
}
```

Note however that you should pass a `dummy` function to `pthread_create` with the appropriate prototype to avoid compilation warnings and potential undefined behavior:

```
void *dummy(void *opaque) {
    /* threads: just say no! */
    return NULL;
}
```

For further improvements, refer to this question:

[Find all primes from 1 million random integers in less than 6 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67484989/find-all-primes-from-1-million-random-integers-in-less-than-6-seconds)

Answer (score 1):

- Avoid floating point math for an integer problem.

The precision of a `double` often exceeds `int`, but not certainly so.  Various FP issues may lead to incorrect results.

The cost of repeated conversion from `int` to `double` can be avoided.

Good compilers will recognize a nearby `n%i` and `n/%` emit code that does both for about same time cost as one.

```
// for (i = 2; i <= sqrt(n); i++) {
for (i = 2; i <= n/i; i++) {
    if (n % i == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

- Handle only odd numbers in the loop.

  ```
  for (i = 3; i <= n/i; i += 2) {
    if (n % i == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
  }
  ```
- Handle only 2 of every 3 odd numbers (more than 7) in a loop.  Do prior `/3` test.

  ```
  for (i = 5; i <= n/i; i += 4) {
    if (n % i == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    i += 2;
    if (n % i == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
  }
  ```
- Create a list of found primes and only attempt division among them.

---

Portability issue: Rather than `long sum = 0; long primeCounter = 0;`, consider `long long`  to reduce chance that `RAND_MAX` is large enough to cause overflow in `long` math`.

---

`If n is divisible by any number between 2 and n/2, it is not prime` comment does not apply here as code is iterating to `sqrt(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

Given OP is attempting to find 1000 prime number candidates, it is likely that a large candidate prime will generate that need to get tested.

To that end, if `RAND_MAX` is say less than 4,000,000,000, consider the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

I suspect this will form the fastest sum, especially if a group of integers with a large prime is tested.